# how to create a temporary table in sql to linq query

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I want to create a temporary table in linq query. I have searched for the solution but didn't succeeded.
here "Node" is temporary table,and "Organization.TblOrganizationUnits" is table in my database.
In linq, How can i create a temporary table and how can I perform different joins and union operation of the above query.
my `sql` query is:

```
string query=string.Format(@"WITH Node (OrganizationUnitId, UnitName,ParentUnitId)
                            AS  (
                                SELECT    Organization.TblOrganizationUnits.OrganizationUnitId, Organization.TblOrganizationUnits.UnitName , Organization.TblOrganizationUnits.ParentUnitId
                                FROM       Organization.TblOrganizationUnits
                                WHERE      OrganizationUnitId ={0}
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT      Organization.TblOrganizationUnits.OrganizationUnitId,  Organization.TblOrganizationUnits.UnitName, Organization.TblOrganizationUnits.ParentUnitId
                                FROM        Organization.TblOrganizationUnits
                                INNER JOIN Node
                                ON          Organization.TblOrganizationUnits.ParentUnitId = Node.OrganizationUnitId
                                )
                            SELECT  OrganizationUnitId, UnitName,ParentUnitId FROM   Node
                            where  OrganizationUnitId not in (SELECT  ParentUnitId FROM   Node)
                           option (maxrecursion 0); ", OrganizationUnitId);
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a temporary table?

Comment: actually i have sql query,but i want to do it in linq expression.in my sql query i have used a temporary table"Node" and i don't know how to convert it into linq.

Comment: Have you tried converting the simple queries into LINQ first? I'd start there. Convert all of your `SELECT..FROM..WHERE` queries into LINQ statements to get comfortable with LINQ before trying to tackle a large query like this.

Comment: ya i have done some basic linq query before it.